# Linux: Triggering desktop notification pop-up when service is executed with systemd

Tags: linux, notifications, systemd, systemd-journald

I want to trigger a desktop notification pop-up when a service is executed with systemd on my Linux desktop. The main reason why I am doing this is that I want to learn how to work with systemd timers and services by creating my own scheduled jobs and I would like to pop-up a desktop notification, when a service/job is executed, just to know that something is happening.

I have created a basic example to do that:

`notifysystemd.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Variable to hold path to systemd job logs
SYSTEMD_LOG_DIR='/home/jay/scheduledJobLogs/systemDJobLogs'
SYSTEMD_JOB_NAME='NotifySystemD'
CURRENT_MONTH=$(date '+%b')

# Send notification to desktop
notify-send 'You can automate and schedule anything with systemd today!'

# Write down in the log
CURRENT_TIME=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M')
LOG_RECORD="${CURRENT_TIME} SystemD notification job executed."

# Create a directory for systemd jobs logging, if it doesn't already exist. And don't error if it does exist
mkdir -p $SYSTEMD_LOG_DIR/$SYSTEMD_JOB_NAME

# Write the log record!
echo $LOG_RECORD >> $SYSTEMD_LOG_DIR/$SYSTEMD_JOB_NAME/$CURRENT_MONTH.txt
```

with this service file:

`notifysystemd.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=A basic service to send a desktop notification using the systemd scheduler
Wants=notifysystemd.timer

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/jay/systemDJobs/notifysystemd.sh
Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus" "XAUTHORITY=/home/jay/.Xauthority"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and this timer file:

`notifysystemd.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Send a notification three minutes after PC start
RefuseManualStart=false # Allow manual starts
RefuseManualStop=false # Allow manual stops

[Timer]
#Execute job if it missed a run due to machine being off
Persistent=true
OnBootSec=180
#File describing job to execute
Unit=notifysystemd.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The service is executed correctly with the correct delay (I can see that in the log created), but I am getting no desktop notification.

I have looked into several questions already asked on this forum:

[systemd service not executing notify-send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608573/systemd-service-not-executing-notify-send)

[notify-send command doesn't launch the notification through systemd service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71101248/notify-send-command-doesnt-launch-the-notification-through-systemd-service)

Which suggest specifying environment variables in either the `.service` file or in the shell script.

I have tried all of them and none led to a notification appearing.

I have done the same with `cronie`, where was sufficient to specify the `DISPLAY` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environement variables the same way as I did in the `notifysystemd.service` file.

Lastly, if there is a better way how to achieve the same result, but which revolves around usage of systemd, I am opened to optimal, or more ergonomic solutions.

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

In systemd instead of notify-send put the output in a file.
Write a bash script and start it on desktop login (so this script **can** notify-send).

In the script write an endless loop.
Use `inotifywait` in the loop to monitor the output file for modification.
(This will suspend your script and won't eat cpu)
After `inotify`, read the content of the file and use `notify-send`.